# What is the the "method of ascending" in the study of elliptic systems in dimension two?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I have read a paper of Z. Shen [1]. In the paper the author mentioned we can deal with two-dimensional elliptic systems by adding a dummy variable (the method of ascending) and use the results on the related three-dimensional problem. I guess it is a standard way to deal with elliptic systems with lower dimensions. However, I do not find any reference about it: can you give me some references or hints?

**Reference**

[1] Zhongwei Shen, "[Convergence rates and Hölder estimates in almost-periodic homogenization of elliptic systems](https://doi.org/10.2140/apde.2015.8.1565)" (English),
Analysis & PDE 8, No. 7, 1565-1601 (2015), DOI: 10.2140/apde.2015.8.1541, [MR3399132](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR3399132), [Zbl 1327.35025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1327.35025).

Comment: Just set the functions to be constant along the dummy variable? Simplest example: if $\Delta u = f$ on the two dimensional ball, set $\tilde{u}(x,y,z) = u(x,y)$ and $\tilde{f}(x,y,z) = f(x,y)$, then $\Delta \tilde{u} = \tilde{f}$ on the three dimensional ball, and then any estimates for solutions of the three dimensional Poisson problem gives an analogous estimate for the two dimensional problem.

Comment: (It is not so much "elliptic" specific: most students of PDE probably saw it first when learning about deriving the fundamental solution for the linear wave equation on $\mathbb{R}^{1+2}$ from that of $\mathbb{R}^{1+3}$.)